# Problem in HelpText Rendering

Tags: visualforce

i have one field of type="checkbox".i have defined helptext while defining field.now on VF page Helptext image is visible but on hover of that image no helptext appears.also on hover ,image color doesn't get dark.What's the issue with that.i am not getting it.

[image]

My code for this field is

```
<apex:inputField style="width:15px" onclick="showLoadingImage();" value="{!con[f]}" />
```

Comment: Post more visualforce code.

Comment: Any luck with this Pankaj?

Answer (score 3):

This seems to work fine for me in Chrome, with the following VF.

[image]

```
<apex:page standardController="Test__c">
<apex:form >
<apex:pageBlock >
<apex:pageBlockSection title="My Content Section" columns="2">
<apex:inputField style="width:15px" value="{!Test__c.MyCheckbox__c}"/>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

As you can see I've used an explicit field reference, I assume your doing something with a Fieldset? This indirection may have something to do with it. Can you try it again with a direct binding, this would eliminate at least any browser incompatibility issue. Which would be shown in the Error console of your browser if so.

Comment: Just checked the same but with dynamic binding (also with all modes for the pageBlock: detail, maindetail, edit, inlineEdit ) - works fine for me.

Comment: This suggests a possible browser scripting error. Pankaj, is there anything reported in the Error console of your browser? Also have you tried using the Developer Tools console of the browser to inspect the page to see if the tooltip is being output to the page?

Comment: @AndrewFawcett No Error in error console..

Comment: <img class="helpOrb" title="" alt="" src="/s.gif"> this is output in firebug for this image.title is null.

Comment: Can you try to isolate your code down a bit further perhaps? Take my example above and create a simple page with only that field on and confirm that works. If that works you likely have something on your main page that is effecting the standard behaviour.